# Change and save .nc files

Tags: powershell

I have a massive amount of .nc files (text files) where I need to change different lines based on their linenumer and content.

Example:

[image]

So far I have:

```
Get-ChildItem I:\temp *.nc -recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $c = ($_ | Get-Content)
    $c = $c -replace "S355J2","S235JR2"
    $c = $c.GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize
    $c = $c -replace $c[3],$c[4]
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText($_.FullName, ($c -join "`r`n"))
}
```

This is not working, however, since it returns only a few PowerShell lines to each file, instead of the original (changed) content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you expect `$c = $c.GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize` to do, but it most likely doesn't do whatever it is you're expecting.

If I understand your question correctly you essentially want to

1. remove the line `pos`,
2. replace the code `S355J2` with `S235JR2`, and
3. remove a section `SI` if it exists.

The following code should work:

```
Get-ChildItem I:\temp *.nc -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) -replace 'pos\r\n\s+' -replace 'S355J2', 'S235JR2' -replace '(?m)^SI\r\n(\s+.*\n)+' |
    Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

`Out-String` mangles the content of the input file into a single string, and the daisy-chained replacement operations modify that string before it's written back to the file. The expression `(?m)^SI\r\n(\s+.*\n)+` matches a line beginning with `SI` and followed by one or more indented lines. The `(?m)` modifier is to allow matching start-of-line in a multiline string, otherwise `^` would only match the beginning of the string.

---

**Edit:** If you need to replace variable text in the 3rd line with the text from the 4th line (thus duplicating the 4th line) you're indeed better off working with an array for that. Delay the mangling of the string array until after that replacement:

```
Get-ChildItem I:\temp *.nc -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $txt = @(Get-Content $_.FullName)
  $txt[3] = $txt[4]
  ($txt | Out-String) -replace 'S355J2', 'S235JR2' -replace '(?m)^SI\r\n(\s+.*\n)+' |
    Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful.

Comment: Removing the section with SI works very smooth. - What I meant with replacing 'pos' with the line below, is that the line where 'pos' is written (3rd line) should be replaced with what is written in the line blow (4th line). Difficulty with that, is that on the third line its not always written 'pos'. Sometimes it has another word, but in all cases i want that word to be replaced by the code that is in the fourth line. Hence my attempt to make an array of the text and interchange linenumbers with each other. Maybe you have a solution for that?

Comment: This is fantastic. So smooth. Thank you.

Comment: So I dont need to define an arry? It does that automatically? How does the script knows im refering to linenumbers?

Comment: `Get-Content` returns an array of strings in the order they're read from the file, hence the array indexes are the line numbers minus 1. The `@(...)` around the cmdlet ensures that the result is an array even if the file is empty or has just one line.

Comment: Thank you for the explainations. it makes it clear for me now :)